# Automatically generate section title slides in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

Is there a way to get beamer to automatically stick in a slide with a centered title whenever I use `\section{title}` or `\subsection{title}` or (heaven forbid) `\subsubsection{title}`? I'm hoping some package or command will do this for every time one of these commands is used, but I would settle for a `\maketitle` type command that would work within each section or subsection.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Minirogue.

Comment: I think this thread is not fully covered. At least, the output of the accepted answer is not nice enough.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the macros `\AtBeginSection`, `\AtBeginSubsection` and `\AtBeginSubsubsection` to automatically execute something at the beginning of each (sub)(sub)section. To create a title frame, `beamer` offers the commands `\sectionpage` and `\subsectionpage`. `\subsubsectionpage` is missing by default, but you can easily define it yourself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}

% Add support for \subsubsectionpage
\def\subsubsectionname{\translate{Subsubsection}}
\def\insertsubsubsectionnumber{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{subsubsection name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection name}\subsubsectionname~\insertsubsubsectionnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{subsubsection title}\insertsubsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}
\def\subsubsectionpage{\usebeamertemplate*{subsubsection page}}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}
\AtBeginSubsection{\frame{\subsectionpage}}
\AtBeginSubsubsection{\frame{\subsubsectionpage}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image: a \subsubsectionpage]

Comment: I think I may want to modify some of this to my preferences, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to just use `\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}`, I get a `! Missing \endgroup inserted.` at the very end of the document. Do you have an idea what is causing this or should I ask a full question?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the "Section X" over title and have just the actual section title?

Comment: Yes, on the code above just delete this part:
  
  `\begin{centering}
        {\usebeamerfont{subsubsection name}\usebeamercolor[fg]    {subsubsection name}\subsubsectionname~\insertsubsubsectionnumber}
        \vskip1em\par`

Comment: @BrianMayer I cannot reproduce your proposal. It is a just reproduction of *diobonas* proposal. - - Please, post a full answer if you think you can answer Luis' question.