# Drawing attention to sections in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I'd like to make the audience pay attention to *sections* since they are topics of the slides that will be presented afterwards and shouldn't be missed, so for every section I define a frame like this:

[image]

here's the code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textarabic{}}
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{blue}{blue}{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE{نمایش تنک}}}
\end{center}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

The sections are shown at the upper right hand corner (the blue rectangle) and the subsections are shown in the grey rectangle. I am trying to find some other methods to make it look more attractive without the need to add lots of code defining new shapes and objects and such.

Comment: why does this have 3 close votes already? it seems like a reasonable question... please post comments with reasons if you plan to vote to close.

Comment: This should be closed yet. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to request less opinion-based answers (if any). Asking to make something "look more attractive" is subjective and not a good fit. Explicitly *define* what you mean by "more attractive" (for example, I want it to show up in red, or there should be an arrow pointing to the section, ...).

Comment: @werner I am not aware of all beamer or tikz options for such a request, so I couldn't be more specific. Perhaps a cloud instead of the rectangle (but then it doesn't look academic, rather childish) or the whole background being blue instead of the blue rectangle.

Comment: A few examples for section pages: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41198/how-can-you-change-what-frame-sectionpage-does-in-beamer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117658/automatically-generate-section-title-slides-in-beamer or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/creating-sections-each-with-title-pages-in-beamers-slides

Comment: If turning the question to a CW question helps, I'd do that. People could suggest what they think would be suitable.

Comment: @Gigili: Perhaps you can first ask questions about design or style at [graphicdesign.se] or [ux.se] to come up with something definitive, then request the specifics here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to choose what your audience will draw their attention to. If you really need to get their attention to the sections, put section slides before each section and spend 5-10 seconds about it verbally.

Otherwise you are wasting valuable attention span to some obscure little text during the presentation.